# How to add space for 4th field in a file with unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

Need to check in a file for 4th field with length 9 if the length is 9 I need to pad a space in that 4th field and make it as 10

Unix server

I used the below logic

```
#!bin/bash
fil_n="/tmp/vishal/09082019/237_20190801143653.creq"
  while IFS= read line
   do
     var=`echo $line|cut -f4 -d "," | grep -v '\#'`
     echo $var
     len=${#var}
     echo $len
     if [ $len -eq 9 ]; then
     var2=" " var3="$var2$var"
      echo "var3 = $var3"
     echo $line | sed -i   "s/${var}/${var3}/g" "$fil_n"
     fi
   done < "$fil_n"
```

but the sed is not padding the replaced value to the file

Note: Search and Replace in same file

File :

```
0008627921,2,A,0FE3B20F,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:54:04,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:59:56,00700,00680,00,02,07799871,1,*,000,0000,  ,    ,0000000000,0008627906,00,0
expected 2 spaces In front of 0FE3B20F
```

**INPUT:**

```
#HEADER,CREQ,014194,07/29/2019,237,AT,08/01/2019,02:36:52 
0008627921,2,A,<space>0FE3B20F,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:54:04,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:59:56,00700,00680,00,02,07799871,1,,000,0000, , ,0000000000,0008627906,00,0
0008627920,2,A,065000075A,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:41:04,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:46:56,00700,00680,00,02,07799870,1,,000,0000, , ,0000000000,0008627905,00,1
#TRAILER,014194,08/01/2019,00000002,0000001360
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
#HEADER,CREQ,014194,07/29/2019,237,AT,08/01/2019,02:36:52
0008627921,2,A,<space><space>0FE3B20F,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:54:04,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:59:56,00700,00680,00,02,07799871,1,,000,0000, , ,0000000000,0008627906,00,0
0008627920,2,A,065000075A,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:41:04,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:46:56,00700,00680,00,02,07799870,1,,000,0000, , ,0000000000,0008627905,00,1
#TRAILER,014194,08/01/2019,00000002,0000001360
```

Comment: `0FE3B20F` is 8 characters, not 9...

Comment: original file already have a space between the character 0FE3B20F

Comment: And the field is not the 4th field

Comment: it is 4th field only

Comment: Is this line: `#HEADER,CREQ,014194,07/29/2019,237,AT,08/01/2019,02:36:52` the header?

Comment: yes leave that header and trailer .. in between that it is required to verify the 4th field with 9 digits if it is then pad a space to it and make it as 10. this 9 field includes one space at front

Comment: Is your input file on one line or on 4 lines?

Comment: We need to know

Comment: Also if your file comes from windows you should convert the EOL characters before doing this operation

Comment: my input file has 2 lines dedicated for header and trailer … rest it fills from database operation... we use unix terminal and server for file receiving and formatiing

Comment: Should we not redefine the question as _How can I make sure that the fourth field has minimum of 10 characters with spaces padded to the left?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{while(length($4)<10){$4=" "$4};print}' test.creq 
0008627921,2,A,  0FE3B20F,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:54:04,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:59:56,00700,00680,00,02,07799871,1,*,000,0000,  ,    ,0000000000,0008627906,00,0
```

**Explanations:**

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` set the field separator as well as the output field separator to `,`
- `while(length($4)<10){$4=" "$4}` pad space in front of the 4th field until it reaches a length of 10
- `print` the line

**Combined in one command:**

```
(cp test.creq backup.creq && awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{while(length($4)<10){$4=" "$4};print}' test.creq > tmp.creq && mv tmp.creq test.creq)
```

You can also use directly the following simplified command using [`sprintf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) similar to the c++ one:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$4 = sprintf("%10s", $4)}1' test.creq
```

**Input:**

```
cat test.creq 
#HEADER,CREQ,014194,07/29/2019,237,AT,08/01/2019,02:36:52 
0008627921,2,A, 0FE3B20F,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:54:04,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:59:56,00700,00680,00,02,07799871,1,,000,0000, , ,0000000000,0008627906,00,0
0008627920,2,A,065000075A,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:41:04,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:46:56,00700,00680,00,02,07799870,1,,000,0000, , ,0000000000,0008627905,00,1
#TRAILER,014194,08/01/2019,00000002,0000001360
```

**Output:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}!/^#/{while(length($4)<10){$4=" "$4};}1' test.creq 
#HEADER,CREQ,014194,07/29/2019,237,AT,08/01/2019,02:36:52 
0008627921,2,A,  0FE3B20F,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:54:04,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:59:56,00700,00680,00,02,07799871,1,,000,0000, , ,0000000000,0008627906,00,0
0008627920,2,A,065000075A,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:41:04,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:46:56,00700,00680,00,02,07799870,1,,000,0000, , ,0000000000,0008627905,00,1
#TRAILER,014194,08/01/2019,00000002,0000001360
```

Comment: original file has space already before the value OFE3B20F so with space it is 9 but expected is 10 digits with 2 spaces and then 0FE3B20F

Comment: the above commands pads 8 spaces in front of the already existing 9 digit including one space

Comment: Just use sprintf().

Comment: allan, I tried with the above one in unix terminal it is still padding 8 spaces

Comment: 0008627921,2,A,<8 spaces>0FE3B20F,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:54:04,CLW,01,07/29/2019,12:59:56,00700,00680,00,02,07799871,1,*,000,0000,  ,            ,0000000000,0008627906,00,0

Comment: @allan Any suggestions... I executed in unix shell and output it gives that field with 8 spaces and 9 characters with total of 17

Comment: @allan Any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you meant you want to pad an 8-character long 4th field to 10, not a 9 to 10...

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } length($4) == 8 { $4 = sprintf("%10s", $4) } 1' input.csv
```

Comment: The O.P. may want to consider `length($4) < 10`. Just an idea ;-) Good luck to all.